# Why is Zeus running slower than RSpec?

Tags: rspec, zeus

Some of the individual tests are lightning fast with Zeus, and others are pretty dang slow.

If I do:

`time rspec spec/`

The result is:

```
Finished in 35.36 seconds
220 examples, 0 failures

real    0m59.018s
user    0m43.723s
sys 0m2.495s
```

But if I use Zeus:

`time zeus rspec spec/`

The result is:

```
Finished in 7 minutes 9 seconds
220 examples, 0 failures

real    7m13.053s
user    0m0.279s
sys 0m0.047s
```

Notice the "user" and "sys" times in both, those line up with what I would expect. However, there's a major disconnect with what the "real" times are showing.

What's up with this?

EDIT: Below is my spec_helper.rb file:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rubygems'
require 'shoulda-matchers'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/rails'
require 'sidekiq/testing'
require "paperclip/matchers"
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'sunspot/rails/spec_helper'
require 'timecop'
# require 'webmock/rspec'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

def spork?
  defined?(Spork) && Spork.using_spork?
end

def setup_environment
  # This file is copied to spec/ when you run 'rails generate rspec:install'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'

  if spork?
    ENV['DRB'] = 'true'
    Spork.trap_method(Rails::Application::RoutesReloader, :reload!)
  end

  Rails.backtrace_cleaner.remove_silencers!

  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction

  RSpec.configure do |config|

    Warden.test_mode!

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    config.before(:suite) do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:transaction)
    end

    # Use transactions by default
    config.before :each do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    config.before(:each) do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after :each do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.mock_with :rspec

    config.after(:each) do
      Warden.test_reset!
    end

    config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
    config.include Capybara::DSL
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.include Warden::Test::Helpers
    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods
    config.include Paperclip::Shoulda::Matchers

    config.before(:each) do
      ::Sunspot.session = ::Sunspot::Rails::StubSessionProxy.new(::Sunspot.session)
    end

    config.after(:each) do
      ::Sunspot.session = ::Sunspot.session.original_session
    end
  end

  OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
end

prefork = lambda {
  setup_environment
}

each_run = lambda {
  if spork?
    ActiveSupport::Dependencies.clear
    FactoryGirl.reload
  end

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/support/**/*.rb"].each {|f| require f}
}

# If zeus is available in the Gemfile it'll be used but we don't force it.
if defined?(Zeus)
  prefork.call
  $each_run = each_run
  class << Zeus.plan
    def after_fork_with_test
      after_fork_without_test
      $each_run.call
    end
    alias_method_chain :after_fork, :test
  end
# Same with spork.
elsif ENV['spork'] || $0 =~ /\bspork$/
  require 'spork'
  Spork.prefork(&prefork)
  Spork.each_run(&each_run)
else
  prefork.call
  each_run.call
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is too much "requires" in spec_helper.rb. You should place them in your Gemfile:

```
group :test do    
    gem 'shoulda-matchers'
    gem 'database_cleaner'
    gem 'selenium-webdriver'
    gem 'timecop' 
    # and so on
end
```

Comment: Just because it's in your Gemfile doesn't mean they're autoloaded in your specs. Some gems require explicit `require` statements. Gemfile is just for Bundler. This also has nothing to do with my original post.